# Using ini file with password having special characters using python configparser

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, configparser

## new.ini file

```
[main]
user_name = username
password = [k!:SU`T&m5@3D\\7Z
```

## python code

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(CONFIG.ini file path)
print(config["main"]["user_name"])
print(config["main"]["password"])
```

output:

```
username
[k!:SU`T&m5@3D\\\\7Z
```

After reading the file, the parsed password is not same as file input password.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please look into the below comments with @Carlos Horn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is still the same, but its representation is confusing you.
The problem is the "\7" which could be interpreted as a special character. To avoid any confusion, python writes a double backslash.
To see the difference, you may write the following two strings:

```py
string_1 = "\7"
string_2 = r"\7"
print(string_1)
print(string_2)

print(repr(string_1))
print(repr(string_2))
```

I hope this helps you to understand the difference in what python displays.

Edit:

There should not be an extra backlash. Please try the following:

```py
import configparser

content = r"""
[main]
user_name = username
password = [k!:SU`T&m5@3D\\7Z
"""
with open('test.ini', mode='w') as file:
    file.write(content)
parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
with open('test.ini', mode='r') as file:
    parser.read_file(file)
assert parser['main']['password'] == r"[k!:SU`T&m5@3D\\7Z"
```

Edit2: Please try the edited code. It should create your ini file and read in the correct password as tested with the assertion.

Edit3:
I just copy pasted your ini file and ran your lines and get the correct output without extra slashes:

```
username
[k!:SU`T&m5@3D\\7Z
```

So could you please show the output of the following lines:

```py
import platform
import sys

print(sys.version)
print(platform.platform())
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

which in my case says:

```
3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
Linux-4.12.14-lp151.28.91-default-x86_64-with-glibc2.10
utf-8
```

Sorry, I cannot help you further, because I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: I understood the representation. 
But I'm trying to find a way to remove the extra adding backslashes to the password string in configparser package. @Carlos Horn

Comment: You edited your ini file content, so do you want two slashes "[k!:SU`T&m5@3D\\7Z" or just one in the password?

Comment: This helps a lot. But I'm trying to send the same password to access a server. Trying to understand is there a way in configparser package that coverts or replaces the code from the double backslashes to single backslashes dynamically if any other variables contains backslashes.
@Carlos Horn

Comment: My password contains two backslashes in ini file. @Carlos Horn
when i parse using configparser. The parser contains 4 backslashes in the variable.

Comment: I edited the answer and cannot reproduce your error. Maybe it is a matter of the operating system...

Comment: When you debug the parser['main']['password'] using pdb, at the particular line. Accessing parser['main']['password'] and print(parser['main']['password']) is completely different.

I need to pass the password parser['main']['password'] to authenticate the server. Where it says Invalid Credentials due to double backslashes.